# click to show or click outside or the same button to hide

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var elem = $(e.target).closest('#click'),
        box  = $(e.target).closest('#box');

    if ( elem.length ) {
        e.preventDefault();
         showbox();
    }else if (!box.length){
         hidebox();
    }
});
```

So if the `showbox();` line is: `$('#box').toggle();` it's working perfectly. But if I use script without toggle, the button's hide stops working.

Here's full example with all details inside: http://jsfiddle.net/8SFMw/

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I click on the box it shouldn't disappear, but I think you already noticed that on the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the `showbox()` function, its that `elem.length` will always return 1 and thus always be true.

try using `.is(":visible")`, something like...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
        if ($('#box').is(":visible")){
            hidebox();
        }else{
            showbox();
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: it would work great, if outside box click would work also. Thank you anyway

Comment: I just tried adding  `$('#box').click(function(){event.stopPropagation();});` with your suggestion and it helped. It works exactly how I need it to work. thank you for you and everybody else who suggested the similar solution! Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8SFMw/10/

Comment: @Simon No problem, I did not realize you wanted to hide\show the box when ANYWHERE on the screen was click, I assumed you only wanted it to happen when the button what clicked. But glad you got it to work.

Comment: Oh!! I didn't try to click to show it anywhere and I just realized that it shows up click anywhere also! That means the working example above isn't working right.

Comment: @Simon then what is it that you are looking for? only the button triggers the hide\show?

Comment: yeah, almost. I need the button to be able show and hide, but also outside box click should hide also. Basically I need exactly the same as it is in my example in the 1st post, but to get it work with function instead of `$('#box').toggle();`

Comment: I found the solution! Here's it if any one need it: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/2hTGu/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is not stop working. Your if statement became true every time and your else statement never executed. So you should change your logic. In case .toggle() even your logic executes if statement it will toggle show and hide. For best practice see this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/8SFMw/11/).

**In CSS:**

```
#box
{
    padding:10px;
    border:solid;
    display:none;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#box.show
{
    margin-top:0px;
    display:block;
}

#box.hide
{
    margin-top:1px;
    display:none;
}
```

**In JS:**

```
var $box = $('#box');
$(document).on('click', function(e) {    
    if ( $box.hasClass('show') ) 
    {
        $box.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        //Some code here
    }
    else
    {
        $box.removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
        //Some code here
    }
});
```

So, of course I assume that you want to use some other logic in future so this is solution for you. If you want to just show and hide in this case just use toggle with out other logic.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I click on the box it shouldn't disappear, but I think you already noticed that on the script. However your script doesn't do exactly that what I need, it disappears on box click and when page is loaded first click on button doesn't work. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the box doesn't disappear When you click on `button#click` when you use `showbox()` instead of `.toggle()`.

This is because when you click on the button itself, your `elem.length != 0`. In other words, it never runs the code inside your `else if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is not working you could do it with

`if ( $('#box').is(":hidden") ) {
...}else{...}`

like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8SFMw/7/)

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't help. I need to work exactly as it on example only with the function instead of toggle